# How can I get one drive to work properly with office

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive, office365

I use MS Word constantly and excel frequently. I prefer to save files in one drive so they can be accessed across multiple computers. However office / one drive is constantly losing track of changes, or losing track of which version is supposed to be current. I am the sole editor of files for which this is the case.

I have settled into a routine of simply incrementing the file number every time I save a file. And yes, that does solve the problem. But its the sort of solution that should have been necessary in 1985 when you routinely incremented a file number on saving.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: why don't you use track changes feature in MS-Office itself ?

Comment: Nope, that won't do it.

Comment: You don't mention what version of Office.  I often seamlessly work on documents that only exist in Onedrive with Word 2013 across multiple computers.

Comment: @Ramhound Only the office 365 version, which should be the current version.

Comment: You should provide that information in the question itself.

Comment: Like @Ramhound I also use Office with OneDrive from multiple computers without issue. These documents are not being opened in multiple instances simultaneously, are they? Someone I know once had a similar problem, only to find out they were leaving the document open and walking away, then editing it again from another computer which overwrote the changes when they saved the originally opened document.

Comment: Nope, never open on more than one machine at a time.

Comment: Are you syncing these documents to the device?  When you make these changes are both devices online syncing those changes?

Comment: What Windows are you using? Is this OneDrive personal or OneDrive business? Are you saving directly to OneDrive cloud or locally, then OneDrive upload the changes to the cloud?

Comment: You need to give some more information about your problem. Just like @Ramhound said...